# Chart.js doesn't show chart while on flask blueprint

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, chart.js

I am having trouble while trying to display chart from chart.js using flask blueprint. It works fine when my code is directly in main app file and I have tried to use it in my blueprint but it doesn't show and I cannot find what needs to be changed in the code.

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

from views.trainings import training_blueprint
from views.workouts import workout_blueprint
from views.users import users_blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'jose'

@app.route('/')
def start():
    return 'hello'

@app.route("/simple_chart2")
def chart():
    legend = 'Monthly Data'
    labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August"]
    values = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 7, 8]
    return render_template('chart.html', values=values, labels=labels, legend=legend)



app.register_blueprint(workout_blueprint, url_prefix='/workouts')
app.register_blueprint(users_blueprint, url_prefix='/users')
app.register_blueprint(training_blueprint, url_prefix='/trainings')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

chart.html:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Chart.js Example</title>
    <!-- import plugin script -->
    <script src='static/Chart.min.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Simple Line Chart</h1>
    <!-- bar chart canvas element -->
    <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    <p id="caption">The chart is displaying a simple line chart.</p>

    <script>
      // Global parameters:
      // do not resize the chart canvas when its container does (keep at 600x400px)
      Chart.defaults.global.responsive = false;

      // define the chart data
      var chartData = {
        labels : [{% for item in labels %}
                   "{{item}}",
                  {% endfor %}],
        datasets : [{
            label: '{{ legend }}',
            fill: true,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
            borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            borderCapStyle: 'butt',
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointBorderWidth: 1,
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
            pointRadius: 1,
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            data : [{% for item in values %}
                      {{item}},
                    {% endfor %}],
            spanGaps: false
        }]
      }

      // get chart canvas
      var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

      // create the chart using the chart canvas
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: chartData,
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

trainings.py (last function):

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, session, url_for, Flask
from werkzeug.utils import redirect

from models.exercise import Excercise
from models.user import requires_login
from models.workout import Workout

training_blueprint = Blueprint('trainings', __name__)

@training_blueprint.route('/ex_index')
@requires_login
def ex_index():
    exercises = Excercise.user_exercises(session['email'])
    return render_template('trainings/ex_index.html', exercises=exercises)


@training_blueprint.route('/ex_index/new_exercise', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@requires_login
def new_exercise():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        exercise = Excercise(name, session['email'])
        exercise.save_to_mongo()
        return redirect(url_for('.ex_index'))
    return render_template('trainings/new_exercise.html')


@training_blueprint.route('/delete/<string:exercise_id>')
@requires_login
def delete_exercise(exercise_id):
    exercise = Excercise.get_by_id(exercise_id)
    if exercise.user_email == session['email']:
        exercise.remove_from_mongo()
    return redirect(url_for('.ex_index'))


@training_blueprint.route('/edit/<string:exercise_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@requires_login
def edit_exercise(exercise_id):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_name = request.form['new_name']
        exercise = Excercise.get_by_id(exercise_id)
        exercise.name = new_name
        exercise.save_to_mongo()

        return redirect(url_for('.ex_index'))
    return render_template('trainings/edit_exercise.html', exercise = Excercise.get_by_id(exercise_id))


@training_blueprint.route('/new_training', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@requires_login
def new_training():
    exercises = Excercise.user_exercises(session['email'])

    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_workout_dict = {}
        for i in range(1,11):
            exercise_name = request.form[f'exercise_multiselect{i}']
            reps = request.form[f'Reps{i}']
            weight = request.form[f'Weight{i}']
            if exercise_name != 'None':
                new_workout_dict[exercise_name] = [reps, weight]
        new_workout = Workout(session['email'], new_workout_dict, request.form['date'])
        new_workout.save_to_mongo()
        return "ello"

    return render_template('trainings/new_training.html', exercises=exercises)


@training_blueprint.route('/chart', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def chart():
    legend = 'Monthly Data'
    labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August"]
    values = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 7, 8]

    return render_template('/chart.html', values=values, labels=labels, legend=legend)
```

Comment: Where is your `chart.html` located? Your other routes in you `training_blueprint` are directed to a `trainings` folder to find html files, but your `chart()` function is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the browser inspector give you any error which helps us to answer it?

Maybe it has to do with your blueprint static folder structure or the js url in the HTML file.

For each blueprint you can optionally specify a template_folder:

```
training_blueprint = Blueprint('training_blueprint', __name__,
                        template_folder='templates')
```

More information
https://hackersandslackers.com/flask-blueprints/

In your HTML you can replace

```
<script src='static/Chart.min.js'></script>
```

with

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='Chart.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: thank you after replacing code in HTML it works fine !